# Skype Bot on Microsoft Bot Framework - No response

Tags: botframework

I've managed to build my first bot and registered it. It works fine with the Web Chat control, but through Skype I'm getting no response. The Skype registration worked and the bot it authorized ("Credentials have been validated."). The bot is enabled too. Just not published yet, but apparently that is not necessary for it to work, no? Inside Skype the bot appears online.
I know that is not much information, but maybe somebody has a few hints?

This is the bot:
https://join.skype.com/bot/d55bb62a-86e8-4eec-be63-4f068e347046

It does not much yet, but it should send a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, I had the wrong Messaging Callback Url in the Skype Bot Portal.

Just for reference, maybe this helps someone:

[image]

Comment: Remy, the same is happening to me :( Works on WebChat, but not on Skype. 
https://join.skype.com/bot/bf97c829-7e47-4bdf-8eb9-1afeffd16888


Is this the right format? 
https:// [mybot] .azurewebsites.net/api/messages

Comment: Your endpoint looks fine. In any case, if the WebChat works, your endpoint is ok. In my case, the Messaging Callback Url was wrong. And the App Secret for Skype, is not the same App Secret that you use inside your C# project. I've added an example pics with my Skype Bot credentials.

Comment: Thanks Remy. All seems to be correct. The issue is somewhere else :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. But nevertheless I would go over all Skype Settings again. If WebChat works, there is really no reason that Skype would not work.

Comment: Well its also working on FB so it's definitely sth with Skype :D Anyway, will figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my bot, using the VS template. It worked in webchat and Slack but it didn't respond in Skype. I think there is a weird bug with the Skype integration(at least in the default VS template) but try to start your message with a " "(space) or "."(dot). If the message contains a special sign the bot responds as expected.
Example:

> '.How are you'
>
> ' Hello'

Comment: Currently getting my Bot to Version 3. But will try it out as soon as it works again.